# Import data from excel to sql returning NULL

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, import-from-excel

I'm trying to import data from an excel sheet into my database, however some data would be imported as NULL. Which includes

> 1) Something that contains '-'. eg. 12345678-9
>
> 2) A number that has a warning on excel that says number stored as text, and when the option convert this to number, it goes from 811123123121014259 to 8.96503E+17

I am importing the data via ASP.NET

```
using (OleDbConnection excelConnection = new OleDbConnection(conStr))
{
    //Create OleDbCommand to fetch data from Excel 
    using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * From [" + SheetName + "]", excelConnection))
    {
        excelConnection.Open();
        using (OleDbDataReader dReader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            using (SqlBulkCopy sqlBulk = new SqlBulkCopy(strConnection))
            {
                //Give your Destination table name 
                sqlBulk.DestinationTableName = "TableName";
                sqlBulk.WriteToServer(dReader);
            }
        }
        excelConnection.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to change your connection string.

> Use this one when you want to treat all data in the file as text, overriding Excels column type "General" to guess what type of data is in the column.

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=c:\myFolder\myExcel2007file.xlsx;Extended Properties="Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1";
```

More informations [here](https://www.connectionstrings.com/excel/).

Comment: It's still imported as NULL

Comment: @BloopieBloops check your connection string again. When this happens it's a connection string related problem.

Comment: Right now, I'm using this: Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR={1};IMEX=1